# Como faço para quando o usuário desmacar o check box diminua -1 do self.points?

Tags: python, pyqt-5

Estou desenvolvendo esse aplicativo (ainda no começo) no PyQt5 para calcular a pontuação dos funcionários de uma empresa baseado se o funcionário atende o critério da questão, e cada questão tem a sua regra, caso atenda essa regra, é somada uma pontuação total deste funcionário.

Minha dúvida é, por exemplo, na 1° questão é somado 1 ponto se for marcado a opção 'SIM', caso a pessoa que esteja avaliando marque sem querer o 'SIM' e depois desmarque-a, no código atual é somada 2 vezes. E como se o programa entendesse que ela marcou duas vezes o 'SIM'. quero que caso isso aconteça, o código diminua 1 ponto da pontuação.

```
import  sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QLineEdit, QPlainTextEdit, QCheckBox
 
questions = [
    '1. Conhece as diretrizes estratégicas da Cooperativa e considera que a implementação dessas sejam fundamentais para o alcance dos objetivos e metas estabelecidos.',
    '2. Entende que o cumprimento da jornada de trabalho seja um padrão pouco relevante.'
    '3. Considera a preservação da qualidade do clima organizacional como fator mais importante do que os esforços para solução de problemas e desenvolvimento dos negócios.'
    
]
 
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.q_list = questions
        self.points = list()
        self.initUI()
    
    
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('ADF Project')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #404040')
        self.display()
 
        self.show()
    
    
    
    def display(self):
        #Labels
        self.addLabel('Nome:', 5,5, 50, 20)
        self.addLabel('Matrícula:', 5, 50, 70, 20)
        self.addLabel('Função:', 330, 50, 50, 20)
        
        #Text Line
        self.addLineText(55, 2, 650, 30)
        self.addLineText(70, 45, 250, 30)
        self.addLineText(380, 45, 250, 30)
        #Buttons
        self.addBtn('Calcular', 720,1,80,35, lambda: print(sum(self.points)))
        
        self.Qdisplay()
        
        
        
        
    
    def Qdisplay(self):
        #Question 1
        self.tst = self.addTextBox(self.q_list[0], 5, 100, 625, 75)
        self.addCheckBox('SIM', 650, 120, 50, 30, True)
        self.addCheckBox('NÃO', 700, 120, 50, 30)
        #Question 2
        self.addTextBox(self.q_list[1], 5, 200, 625, 75)
        self.addCheckBox('SIM', 650, 220, 50, 30,)
        self.addCheckBox('NÃO', 700, 220, 50, 30, True)
    
        self.addCheckBox('SIM', 650, 320, 50, 30,)
        self.addCheckBox('NÃO', 700, 320, 50, 30,True)
    
    def addBtn(self, btnName: str, ax: int, ay: int, aw: int, ah: int, function=None, style=None) -> None:
        btn = QPushButton(btnName, self)
        btn.move(ax, ay)
        btn.resize(aw, ah)
        if not style:
            btn.setStyleSheet('color: white; font-weight: bold')
        else:
            btn.setStyleSheet(style)
        if function:
            btn.clicked.connect(function)
        
    def addLabel(self,text: str, ax: int, ay:int, aw: int, ah: int) -> None:
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText(text)
        label.move(ax, ay)
        label.resize(aw, ah)
        label.setStyleSheet('color: white')
 
    def addLineText(self, ax: int, ay:int, aw: int, ah: int) -> None:
        line = QLineEdit(self)
        line.move(ax, ay)
        line.resize(aw, ah)
        line.setStyleSheet('color: white')
 
    def addTextBox(self, text: str, ax: int, ay:int, aw: int, ah: int) -> None:
        txt = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        txt.setPlainText(text)
        txt.move(ax, ay)
        txt.resize(aw, ah)
        txt.setStyleSheet('color: white')
    
    def addCheckBox(self, text: str, ax: int, ay:int, aw: int, ah: int, regua=False) -> None:    
        box = QCheckBox(self)
        box.setText(text)
        box.move(ax, ay)
        box.resize(aw, ah)
        box.setStyleSheet('color: white')
        if regua:
            box.clicked.connect(lambda: self.points.append(1))
 
 
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    qt = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = App()
    sys.exit(qt.exec_())
```

Imagens abaixo:

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL8zn.png)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNN36.png)